# Dash figure title positioning

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm currently designing a dashboard with Dash.
In the middle of my page I have 3 divs side by side which each have a datepicker callback and receive a figure. The three divs start on the same pixel and have exactly the same height. This part looks like this at the moment:

[image]

I now have two design requirements that I'm unable to both fulfill at the same time:

- The customer asks that each of the three red lines (below the word Figure) have the same width as the plot. As seen in the picture I am able to do this if they're part of the figure (Please note that these are NOT underlined titles but px.line()). I am not able to do this easily in html since I don't know beforehand what width the plot will have exactly (and this changes dynamically with screen size and also word length of the x axis labeling
- The three lines should be perfectly on the same height. This is of course easy in Html but I can't get it to work in plotly/dash (The titles which are currently plot titles should also be on the same height. This would also easy in Html and shouldn't lead to any problems)

Possible solutions:

- Change the titles and their lines to Html. After the plot has rendered, get the plot width and change the line width to the same value. Seems doable but pretty hacky
- Find a solution that's close enough for some standard resolution. Will still fail at others or when zooming etc.
- Find a solution in plotly. What I basically need is "Draw a line y pixels below the top of the container". Maybe I overlooked something here?
- Convince the client that this (not even great/special) design isn't worth the hassle and just do something that works and still looks ok. Doable but I wonder if it's really necessary.

The code for all three figures is pretty long, so here's just the part which affects their titles and positioning:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=None,
        cells=dict(values=[['Ausschuss', 'Gutmenge', 'Ausschussquote'], [ausschuss, gutmenge, str(quote).replace('.',',')]],
        align='right',
        font=dict(family='Arial', size=14),
        height=28
        ))])
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(header_fill_color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')) #this gets rid of the title cells
fig.add_shape(type='line',x0=0, y0=1, x1=1, y1=1, xref='paper', yref='paper', line=dict(color='rgb(225,18,58)', width=1))
fig.update_layout(title=dict(text="<b>Figure 2</b>  " + icon, font_family='Arial', yanchor='top', xanchor='left', xref='paper', x=0.01))
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=50, b=20))
return fig
```

All three figures position the line in the same way

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think change title to `html` is a good way. Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Figure 1',className='text-left'),
            html.Hr(style={'color':'rgb(225,18,58)','height':2}),
            dcc.Graph(id='figure_1',figure={},style={'height':200})
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Figure 2',className='text-left'),
            html.Hr(style={'color':'rgb(225,18,58)','height':2}),
            dcc.Graph(id='figure_2',figure={},style={'height':200})
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Figure 3',className='text-left'),
            html.Hr(style={'color':'rgb(225,18,58)','height':2}),
            dcc.Graph(id='figure_3',figure={},style={'height':200})
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1}),         
    ], className='p-2 align-items-stretch'),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=1117)
```

So here we will use `html.Hr` instead of add shape to title.

And here is the Output (Cannot upload to stackoverflow so please use this link):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hoatranobita/Jobs/main/Screenshot%202022-09-29%20085023.png?token=GHSAT0AAAAAABYDKEWVJ4UYQUDNW26XXINEYZU7UGQ

Comment: thanks for your comment and your effort. It's the solution I had at first. The problem is: It doesn't fit the requirement of having the red lines with the same width as the graph...

Comment: @Suecoviejo: So you mean that the red lines need to be fit with light blue part (chart_background)?